# How can I allow the user to change the target audience of a post with Facebook SDK FeedDialogBuilder on Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm building an android app, and I am going through the Facebook SDK examples, such as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I can use the `FeedDialogBuilder` to create a story to share, but it only gives the options `Share` and `Cancel`, and doesn't give me the ability to set the audience (a particular friend, a list, etc.).

Is this possible using the `FeedDialogBuilder`, or do I need to request publish permissions and build my own facebook sharer?

Here's the code I'm using, after successfully logging in:

```java
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
    params.putString("display", "touch");
    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [setTo(String)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder#setTo%28String%29) method in FeedDialogBuilder.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I'm kind of disappointed that there isn't a way for the user to do this in the dialogue itself, but I can work around that.